# Convert a column in a data frame that has values as a list of lists as numeric

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    date         B  C   D   E
0   04/06/2019  258 994 761 [1, 46, 36, 7457, 456]
1   05/06/2019  748 181 565 [3453, 45]
2   07/06/2019  185 876 107 [4976, 46, 57, 7, 3]
3   08/06/2019  241 386 728 [4, 6457, 4]
4   09/06/2019  516 579 596 [65]
```

I would like to convert df['E'] as a numeric data type. The reason for that is that my goal is to plot the maximum value of E and the average value over time.

I already tried to convert using:

```
df['E'].infer_objects()
df['E'].astype(np.int16)
```

But it did not work...

Comment: Do you want to convert a list to numeric (not possible)? Or do you want to convert the list entries to numeric?

Comment: I want to convert the list entries to numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
df['E'].apply(lambda x:np.array(x,dtype=np.int32))
```

For max and mean

```
df['E_max'].apply(lambda x:x.max())
df['E_mean'].apply(lambda x:x.mean())
```

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

`infer_objects` isn't really for what you think it's for.  From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html):

> Attempts soft conversion of object-dtyped columns, leaving non-object and **unconvertible** columns unchanged. The inference rules are the same as during normal Series/DataFrame construction.

This just checks if an object column can be converted to numeric or some other format recognized by `pandas`.

---

If you want `E` to be truly numeric in the eyes of `pandas`, you need to expand each entry of each list to its own column, so that you are storing actual numeric types and not Python objects.

```
E = pd.DataFrame(df.E.to_numpy().tolist())
```

```
      0       1     2       3      4
0     1    46.0  36.0  7457.0  456.0
1  3453    45.0   NaN     NaN    NaN
2  4976    46.0  57.0     7.0    3.0
3     4  6457.0   4.0     NaN    NaN
4    65     NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Now that you have this reference frame, you can use `min` and `max` directly on this frame.  Using vectorized methods will be ***much*** faster than an approach using `apply`

```
df.assign(**E.agg(['mean', 'max'], 1))
```

```
         date    B    C    D                       E    mean     max
0  04/06/2019  258  994  761  [1, 46, 36, 7457, 456]  1599.2  7457.0
1  05/06/2019  748  181  565              [3453, 45]  1749.0  3453.0
2  07/06/2019  185  876  107    [4976, 46, 57, 7, 3]  1017.8  4976.0
3  08/06/2019  241  386  728            [4, 6457, 4]  2155.0  6457.0
4  09/06/2019  516  579  596                    [65]    65.0    65.0
```